# Replacing words containing at least one element of a list - Python / RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of special characters. I want to apply a RegEx function that replaces words containing at least one element of a list with a comma (",").

So far, using the following code, I know how can I replace characters but I do not know how to do this with the entire word.

```py
characters_list = ['%' , ':' , '(']

text = "Fun%( fact: About 71,3% of the Earth's surface is water-covered: and the oceans hold about 96.5% of all Earth's water."


regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape,characters_list)))
text = regex.sub(",", text)
```

I want the string "text" to become:

> ", , About , of the Earth's surface is , and the oceans hold about , of all Earth's water."

(All the words containing at least one element from my list "characters_list" have been changed to a comma)

Comment: Did your code not work? If so, please describe the problem: are you getting errors? If so, post the full traceback. Is the output incorrect? If so, post the expected output and the one you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without regex

```
>>> ' '.join((',' if any(c in word for c in characters_list) else word) for word in text.split())
", , About , of the Earth's surface is , and the oceans hold about , of all Earth's water."
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall`:

```
' '.join([',' if re.findall('|'.join(map(re.escape,characters_list)), s) else s 
          for s in text.split(' ')])
```

Output:

```
", , About , of the Earth's surface is , and the oceans hold about , of all Earth's water."
```

Comment: Perfect! Tkank you Chris, it's even shorter than my code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub`:

```
import re

characters_list = ['%' , ':' , '(']
text = "Fun%( fact: About 71,3% of the Earth's surface is water-covered: and the oceans hold about 96.5% of all Earth's water."

print(re.sub( '|'.join(r'(?:[^\s]*{}[^\s]*)'.format(re.escape(c)) for c in characters_list), ',', text ))
```

Prints:

```
, , About , of the Earth's surface is , and the oceans hold about , of all Earth's water.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, If you make your code more human-readable, write your code just like this:

```
import re

text = "Fun%( fact: About 71,3% of the Earth's surface is water-covered: and the oceans hold about 96.5% of all Earth's water."
replaced = re.sub(r'\S+(%|:|\()', ',', text)

print(replaced)
```

Output :

```
, , About , of the Earth's surface is , and the oceans hold about , of all Earth's water.
```